# Google Sheets: SUMIF, Array, Multiple Ranges, Multiple Conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, multiple-conditions

Using Google Sheets, I'm trying to sum two different, non-contiguous ranges based on and/or logic.

My preference is to refer to the conditions by cell reference, e.g.:
`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(E3:E9, B2:B4, D3:D9))+SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(B13:B16, B2:B4, A13:A16))))`

I'd also be happy to just do something like this:
`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(E3:E9, {"ca";"cc";"ck"}, D3:D9))+SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(B13:B16, {"ca";"cc";"ck"}, A13:A16))))`

Unfortunately, neither of these approaches gives me the correct answer.

This is the formula that gives me a correct answer when using Excel:
`=SUM(SUMIF(E3:E9, {"ca","cc","ck"}, D3:D9))+SUM(SUMIF(B13:B16, {"ca","cc","ck"}, A13:A16))`

I've set up a test Google Sheet here:
[SUMIF, Array, Multiple Ranges, Multiple Conditions](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9YBjIQ82bTkJ72wBTYIk4jCq9HAmJS6W-AJzQnr93E/edit?usp=sharing)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(SUMIF(E3:E9, B2:B4, D3:D9))+SUM(SUMIF(B13:B16, B2:B4, A13:A16)))`